# How to Create a User and Group in User Resource

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am creating a user on my RHEL box with the command:

```
useradd -d <home_path> -m -s <shell_path> -U <name>
```

where I want the group to be created when the user is created.  The important part is the -U flag.

How do I implement this in Chef?  So far I have

```
user 'name' do
  comment 'comment'
  shell '<shell_path>'
  home '<home_path>'
  manage_home true
  action :create
end
```

I know I can create a group using the group resource, but that creates a group with a separate ID.  Is there a way to implement the -U flag in the user resource?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any default method for this. If this functionality was highly critical for you, you could implement this functionality with a custom resource provider.

As you mentioned with the `group` resource, the typical method in Chef would be to create your `group` resource first, and assign it a specific `gid`. Then create your `user` resource, and give the `user` a `uid` and `gid` attribute that matches the `gid` given to the `group`. This gives you the result of having a userid that matches the groupid.

For example:

```
group 'name_group' do
  gid '2000'
  action :create
end

user 'name_user' do
  uid '2000'
  gid '2000'
  action :create
end
```

Reference:

- https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html
- https://docs.chef.io/resource_group.html